# Good way of handling data and embedding it?

Tags: c#, file, visual-studio-2012, audio

I'm making a random name generator in Visual Studio and currently the program plays the name for you like this:

Name generated:

```
BobJohn
```

Play sound:

```
Bob.wav
```

Play sound:

```
John.wav
```

So it looks for the .wav files in the same folder as the .exe is located, which is the debug folder right now.
Of course I would much prefer if I could just hand out an executable, instead of handing out all the sound files. How do I handle this in an adequate/proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed them in the resources. See this link for help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx